# Trying to join two dataframes by member but getting a series error - "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'user'"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's the code and output. I'm trying to work through "Practical Time Series" by Nielsen and most issues in the code I've been able to resolve but this one has me stuck probably due to my lack of fundamentals in python. Much appreciate your help

````
>>agg_don.head()

user  timestamp 
0.0   2015-03-30    25.0
      2015-04-06     0.0
      2015-04-13     0.0
      2015-04-20     0.0
      2015-04-27     0.0
Name: amount, dtype: float64```

>>>for user, user_email in all_email.groupby('user'):
>>>    user_donations = agg_don[agg_don.user == user]
    
>>>    user_donations.set_index('timestamp', inplace = True)
>>>    user_email.set_index ('week', inplace = True)
    
>>>    user_email = all_email[all_email.user == user]
>>>    user_email.sort_values('week').set_index('week')
    
>>>    df = pd.merge(user_email, user_donations, how = 'left', 
                  left_index = True,
                  right_index = True)
>>>    df.fillna(0)
    
>>>    df['user'] = df.user_x
>>>    merged_df = merged_df.append(df.reset_index()
                                 [['user', 'week', 'emailsOpened', 'amount']])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-2d13f6100bd8> in <module>
      1 for user, user_email in all_email.groupby('user'):
----> 2     user_donations = agg_don[agg_don.user == user]
      3 
      4     user_donations.set_index('timestamp', inplace = True)
      5     user_email.set_index ('week', inplace = True)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5137             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5138                 return self[name]
-> 5139             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5140 
   5141     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'user'
````

Comment: Welcome to SO Caps! Can I assume the code you posted is part of the execution, i.e. you tried to run the code with changing for loop from 
```member_donations = agg_donations[agg_donations.member
 == member]``` to ```user_donations = agg_don[agg_don.user == user]```  And the error is coming from the second codebase?

Comment: Sorry, so I copy pasted the code from the book. I did end up updating all the fields to user and it still doesn't work. Just updated everything in the post. Thank you for the welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The assignment of this line is causing you trouble:

```
user_donations = agg_don[agg_don.user == user]
```

has 2 folds:

- `user` in `agg_don.user` is the `agg_don` DataFrame's column. `agg_don` has the first column as `member` as you posted on the first command with `agg_don.head()`. Wherever the `agg_don` was formed, it still refers to `member` attribute.
- `user` as the comparison object is the item you are iterating through the user array.

You can solve in two ways: (I suggest the first one as you want consistency with your naming standards for objects)

1. Solution: Modify the formation of the `agg_don` DataFrame's first column from `member` to `user` so when you run `agg_don.head()` you get `user` as the first column
2. Solution: Change the for loop to check `agg_don.member` column value, i.e. :

```
user_donations = agg_don[agg_don.member == user]
```

Comment: Sorry, so I copy pasted the code from the book. I did end up updating all the fields to user and it still doesn't work. Just updated everything

Comment: You agg_don dataframe looks a bit suspicious, it does not display a value for each user/member. How did you download the data? Checking the book, it does not give any instructions for accessing/constructing the dataset. Can you post the result of `agg_don.keys()` and `agg_don.shape`?